# How to execute a non static method from a static method

Tags: java, android, static-methods, execution

I am new to android/java development so I'm having a few issues, this is one of them.
I want to use the result returned in recevieResults in getTickets. I tried to make getTickets static but it has

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
```

and so the method being Static doesn't allow for getApplicationContext.

```
public static void receiveResults(String result2) {

usersXML = result2; 


}

public void getTickets() {

//this method users usersXML from above and needs to execute after receiving the results

}
```

Comment: Change to `public static void getTickets(Context ctx)` and replace `getApplicationContext()` with `ctx`. You have to pass the `Context` from your activity/fragment/whatever though.

Comment: How do I pass the context from my activity? Sorry for my lack of knowledge I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @user3785656 Is there any specific reasons why you are making your receiveResults(..) method static?

Comment: I send results from another activity to the activity where these methods were - It doesn't execute in the right order if I just make the result variable static. Hope that makes sense! Thanks

Comment: You can't call a non-static method from a static method. You'll have to change one of them...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class:

```
public class ViewTicket extends Activity {
    public static <result> recieveResults(Context context, String result2) {
        ViewTicket ticket = (ViewTicket) context;

        return <result>
    }

    public void getTickets(<result> result) {
        // user <result> as you wish.
        SharedPreference pref = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    }


}
```

Call the static method and pass the object to it.

```
ViewTicket myTicket = new ViewTicket();
<result> = ViewTicket.recieveResults(myTicket, "<someString>");

myTicket.getTickets(<result>);
```

Comment: You should probably replace "Activity" with your activity's name since it is extending activity.

Comment: I tried:                                                       public static void receiveResults(String result2) {

usersXML = result2; 
getTickets(this);

}

public void getTickets(Context context) {
ViewTickets _activity = (ViewTickets) context;
SharedPreferences pref = _activity.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
//this method users usersXML from above and needs to execute after receiving the results

}

Comment: In another activity I used that method to pass the result  viewTickets.receiveResults(result); So I'll need to add in context to that as well wont I?

Comment: Updated answer, I think this is what you need.